# Preferred method for binding in MVVM, Data Template in Resources file or just DataContext in View itself?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

This one has got me stumped as I THOUGHT I looked at everything but I must be missing something.  I have went off the traditional MVVM pattern from the MSDN magazine:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

while learning MVVM.  However I usually copy most of the code and then replace it as I need to but today I wanted to build something from scratch and saw that there may be more to it than  I thought.  MVVM appeared to not work with bindings when I used the resource dictionary but does with datacontext directly.  This question ultimately wants to find other developers suggested use of binding they find.

**Summary of question is this: Why does the 'DataTemplate' in the Resource Dictionary appear to not work shown below but a direct 'DataContext' method does with a view right away for bindings?**

Is it because I am doing a mixture of code behind with settings views in the code behind.  Or potentially because of something else.  It appears my property and it's implementation are set correct in the viewmodel if I set the 'DataContext' directly in the View's XAML, but why not in the Resource Dictionary?  I thought the advantage of that method was you could set a bunch of relationships all at once.  I am curious if there is some other setting need to be done to get it to work.  It is curious in the main example of the MVVM method they use Data Templates yet it appears there is more to setting them up than I am doing to get their 'bindings' to work.

**WHAT DID NOT WORK FOR ME:**

I attempted to do some very basic stuff in a main window xaml, leaving some of my code out to make it even simpler:

Main Window XAML:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dxc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/charts" x:Class="WPFTesting12_2.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel x:Name="dockpanel">
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="30">
                <MenuItem Header="Charting">
                    <MenuItem Header="MVVMDataBound" x:Name="mnuDataBoundSeriesMVVMCharting" Click="mnuDataBoundSeriesMVVMCharting_OnClick"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <TextBlock Height="5" Background="Black" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
            <DockPanel x:Name="dockchildren" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Main Window Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }


        private void mnuDataBoundSeriesMVVMCharting_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            View.DataBoundMVVMChart c = new DataBoundMVVMChart();

            dockchildren.Children.Clear();
            dockchildren.Children.Add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Resource Dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:WPFTesting12_2.View"
                    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WPFTesting12_2.ViewModel"
                    >
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel}">
    <vw:DataBoundMVVMChart/>
 </DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Wheat"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Menu">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Wheat"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

View for DataBoundMVVMChart.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFTesting12_2.View.DataBoundMVVMChart"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTesting12_2.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="..\Resources.xaml"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="TesterContent"/>
            </Menu>
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Width="300" x:Name="label" Height="50" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="24"  Content="{Binding Path=HelloString}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel to bind to the View above:

```
namespace WPFTesting12_2.ViewModel
{
    class DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _HelloString;

        public string HelloString
        {
            get { return _HelloString; }
            set 
            {
                _HelloString = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("HelloString");
            }
        }

        public DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel()
        {
            HelloString = "Hello there from the ViewModel";
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Okay now the binding will fail in the view but yet the resources of the color will come in.  So I was thinking I did something wrong but code behind will get the property right away.  So let's move on:

**WHAT DID WORK:**

Magicially if I just add these four lines to the view:

Add this to the declarations in the 'UserControl' segment at top:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTesting12_2.ViewModel"
```

Then set a reference to the UserControl's DataContext:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Its important to realize when working with WPF that there are two layers: the data layer (`DataContext`) and the UI layer (the XAML).

Bindings are used to pull data from the data layer into the View layer.

When you write

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

You are telling WPF that it should create a new instance of `DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel` and use it for the data layer of that UserControl.

When you write

```
<Label Content="{Binding HelloString}" />
```

you are telling the Label to look in its data layer (the `DataContext`) for a property called "HelloString", and use it for the `Content` property.

If the property "HelloString" does not exist in the data layer (which it does not unless you set the `DataContext` like you did with `<UserControl.DataContext>`), the binding will fail and nothing gets displayed except for a binding error in your output window.

Your `DataTemplate` from your `ResourceDictionary` is something different from the `DataContext`.

In fact, a `ResourceDictionary` is just what it sounds like - a dictionary of resources that WPF can use in the application when needed. But objects in the Dictionary are not by default part of the application's UI itself. Instead, they need to be referenced in some way to be used.

But back to your `DataTemplate`

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel}">
    <vw:DataBoundMVVMChart/>
</DataTemplate>
```

WPF uses DataTemplates to know how to draw specific types of objects. In your case, this `DataTemplate` is telling WPF that anytime it needs to draw an object of type `DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel`, it should do so by using a `DataBoundMVVMChart`.

To insert an object into the UI, a `Content` property is normally used, such as

```
MyLabel.Content = new DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel();
```

or

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeDataboundChartViewModelProperty}" />
```

I actually started out learning MVVM with the exact same [article](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&checkda=1&ct=1368037593&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn%24msdn%24msdn&wreply=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx&lc=1033&id=254354&mkt=en-US) you linked in your question, and had a lot of trouble figuring it out as well, which lead me to doing a little blogging about WPF/MVVM aimed specifically for beginners like me :)

If you're interested, I have a few blog articles about WPF/MVVM that may help you understand the technology better.

- [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)
- [A simple MVVM example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/)

As for your actual question:

> Preferred method for binding in MVVM, Data Template in Resources file or just DataContext in View itself?

I prefer using a `DataTemplate` in the `.Resources` somewhere, as then your UI is not specifically tied with one specific `DataContext`.

This is especially important when creating re-usable controls with MVVM. For example, if you have a `CalculatorUserControl`, and you assigned it a `DataContext` in the control itself such as with `<UserControl.DataContext>`, then you could never use that `CalculatorUserControl` with any other `DataContext` other than the one that is created when the control is created.

So typically I set the `DataContext` for the entire application once at startup, and use `DataTemplates` to tell WPF how to draw the different `ViewModels` or `Models` in my application.

My entire application exists in the data layer, and the XAML is merely a user-friendly interface to interact with the data layer. (If you want to see a code sample, check out my [Simple MVVM Example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) post)

Comment: I follow what you are writing but you lose me when you state the part about inserting an object into the UI.  Are you speaking of ther outer layer at the MainWindow.xaml or the inner at the called userControl?  I am just confused as I get in essence what the Data Template is doing but not why it is not working if I am referencing the ResourceDictionary and it picks up my color setttings but not the template part.  When I look at the example it appears everything is hooked up right, yet everytime I usually do MVVM I copy that whole example.  Thanks for your examples I will take a look at them.

Comment: @djangojazz WPF allows you to insert any `object` into the UI tree. By default WPF draws all items it doesn't know how to draw with a `TextBlock` showing the `.ToString()` of the object, however `DataTemplates` can be used to tell WPF how to render the object. As an example, change your menu click command to `dockchildren.Children.Add(new DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel());`. You would normally see something like "WPFTesting12_2.ViewModel.DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel" in the UI, however because of your `DataTemplate` in `<Window.Resources>`, it will get drawn using a `DataBoundMVVMChart` instead.

Comment: @djangojazz (Oops, I forgot `DockPanels` only allow UI objects to be added to them, so you'd need to use a control that allows any object to be added for the example in my above comment to work, such as a `<ContentControl>` or a `<Label>`: `MyContentControl.Content = new DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel();`)

Comment: That works perfectly.  I understanded the concept in your blog and what H B said on seperate of UI and code, what was not getting through to me was the object constraints of DockPanel not letting data through and my implementation of the UI, NOT the viewModel.  I was not getting why I could create a view and get some of the stuff, but when I heard child elements of dock doesn't get data, only UI, that made more sense.  Once I applied a 'Content Presenter' child element in the parent dock it worked right away when setting the method you stated.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use implicit `DataTemplates` you have to use the **view-model-first** approach, you however add a **view** to your `DockPanel` without a view-model as its context. If you simply add the respective view-model (to a `ContentControl` or `ItemsControl`), the view will be created automatically from the `DataTemplate` with the view-model as its `DataContext`.

e.g.

```
<ItemsControl Name="ic"/>
```

```
ic.Items.Add(new DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel());
```

I personally prefer this over **view-first** (e.g. adding a view which then assigns its own `DataContext`), because you usually want references to the view-models, the view is only secondary and manipulated indirectly by interacting with the view-model.

Comment: I am confused by your answer as I thought you had to create the views manually still as that is what the data template did was relate an existing view object to an existing viewmodel object.  Are you meaning the view should be made of the dock panel and it could have many relations to many viewmodels?  You will have to forgive me as I am still trying to learn MVVM on a deeper level.

Comment: `DataTemplates` are blueprints for what *should be created* to display a certain data-type. If you add a view-model to some control that supports it (`DockPanel` only allows controls (thus views) to be added, not data) said blueprint will be executed and a view for that view-model is created. If you use `DataTemplates` you should not create views yourself, that is the whole point of using them. In terms of relationships it's usually 1 view-model to 1 view, what i said has nothing to do with many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Okay I guess then my only frame of reference is the MSDN example then and in that example they do create the views.  So is my template not working due to the nature of data not being allowed in a dock control?  If I changed it to be the more traditional tab control in the MSDN example it would still need a portion of the viewmodel to add things like: ic.dockpanel.Add(new DataBoundMVVMChartViewModel));?  I am basically trying to wonder if the layer of control is always at the top viewmodel and you can't just start a control with access to a viewmodel with data templates in the middle of nowhere

Comment: @djangojazz The MSDN example creates a `TabControl` with the `ItemsSource` property bound to a collection of `Workspace` objects. What that does behind the scenes is create a `TabItem` for each object in the collection, and inserts each `Workspace` object into the `TabItem` using a `ContentPresenter` (`<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }" />'). WPF normally doesn't know how to draw a `Workspace` object, however there is a `DataTemplate` in the `.Resources` which tells WPF how to draw the object, so that template is used to render the `Workspace` object.

Comment: That helps a lot, so in the most basic explanation I would have to load a viewmodel, not a view as I did to my dock in code behind, first and only certain objects accept that type?  Dock Control not being one of them.  I need to keep at MVVM, it seems like once it is set up right it is easy to add to.  But initial setup can be a pain.

Comment: @djangojazz I think the only way to insert a non-UI object into the UI is to use either a `Content` property or an `ItemsSource` property. `Content` is for single objects, while `ItemsSource` is for lists of objects. Typically you'll most often see a `<ContentControl>` object used for single objects, while an `<ItemsControl>` is the most basic form to insert a collection of objects in the UI.

Comment: @Rachel: You can also add items directly to the `ItemsControl.Items` and it will work as well. Further for single objects i use a `ContentPresenter` more often unless i need the additional properties you have on a `ContentControl`. (`ContentPresenters` also conveniently stretch by default).