# wpf - One ViewModel for dynamic Tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Is it possible to have one `ViewModel` for multiple dynamic `Tabs`? Meaning that, whenever I create a new tab, it should use the same instance of `ViewModel` so I can retrieve information and also prevent each Tab from sharing data/showing the same data.

The setting I'm thinking of using it in would be for a payroll application where each employee's payslip can be updated from each tab. So the information should be different in each `Tab`.

Is this possible?

---

**Update:** Added code

**MainViewModel where Tabs Collection is handled:**

```
public ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> Workspaces { get; set; }
public MainViewModel()
{
    Workspaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel>();
    Workspaces.CollectionChanged += Workspaces_CollectionChanged;
}

void Workspaces_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count != 0)
            foreach (WorkspaceViewModel workspace in e.NewItems)
                workspace.RequestClose += this.OnWorkspaceRequestClose;

        if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count != 0)
            foreach (WorkspaceViewModel workspace in e.OldItems)
                workspace.RequestClose -= this.OnWorkspaceRequestClose;
    }

    private void OnWorkspaceRequestClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CloseWorkspace();
    }

    private DelegateCommand _exitCommand;
    public ICommand ExitCommand
    {
        get { return _exitCommand ?? (_exitCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => Application.Current.Shutdown())); }
    }

    private DelegateCommand _newWorkspaceCommand;
    public ICommand NewWorkspaceCommand
    {
        get { return _newWorkspaceCommand ?? (_newWorkspaceCommand = new DelegateCommand(NewWorkspace)); }
    }

    private void NewWorkspace()
    {
        var workspace = new WorkspaceViewModel();

        Workspaces.Add(workspace);

        SelectedIndex = Workspaces.IndexOf(workspace);

    }

    private DelegateCommand _closeWorkspaceCommand;
    public ICommand CloseWorkspaceCommand
    {
        get { return _closeWorkspaceCommand ?? (_closeWorkspaceCommand = new DelegateCommand(CloseWorkspace, () => Workspaces.Count > 0)); }
    }

    private void CloseWorkspace()
    {
        Workspaces.RemoveAt(SelectedIndex);
        SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private int _selectedIndex = 0;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            _selectedIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
        }
    }
```

**WorkspaceViewModel:**

```
public PayslipModel Payslip { get; set; }

    public WorkspaceViewModel()
    {
        Payslip = new PayslipModel();
        SaveToDatabase = new DelegateCommand(Save, () => CanSave);

        SelectAll = new DelegateCommand(Select, () => CanSelect);

        UnSelectAll = new DelegateCommand(UnSelect, () => CanUnSelect);
    }

    public ICommand SaveToDatabase
    {
        get; set;
    }

    private bool CanSave
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    private async void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Payslip.Amount.ToString());
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            foreach (var en in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                var exceptionDialog = new MessageDialog
                {
                    Message = { Text = string.Format("{0}, {1}", en.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, en.Entry.State) }
                };

                await DialogHost.Show(exceptionDialog, "RootDialog");

                foreach (var ve in en.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    exceptionDialog = new MessageDialog
                    {
                        Message = { Text = string.Format("{0}, {1}", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage) }
                    };

                    await DialogHost.Show(exceptionDialog, "RootDialog");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exceptionDialog = new MessageDialog
            {
                Message = { Text = string.Format("{0}", ex) }
            };

            await DialogHost.Show(exceptionDialog, "RootDialog");
        }

    }


    public event EventHandler RequestClose;
    private void OnRequestClose()
    {
        if (RequestClose != null)
            RequestClose(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private string _header;
    public string Header
    {
        get { return _header; }
        set
        {
            _header = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Header");
        }
    }
```

**Payroll UserControl where WorkspaceViewModel is DataContext:**

```
public Payroll()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new WorkspaceViewModel();
}
```

**Payroll.xaml Tabcontrol:**

```
<dragablz:TabablzControl ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
            <dragablz:TabablzControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dragablz:TabablzControl.ItemTemplate>
            <dragablz:TabablzControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Margin="16">
                        <local:TabLayout DataContext="{Binding Path=Payslip, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="tabLayout"/>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dragablz:TabablzControl.ContentTemplate>
        </dragablz:TabablzControl>
```

This works as expected, each tab displays different info and bindings work okay. However, I'm unable to retrieve the info in the MessageBox.

Comment: Can't you just add the same instance to the same source collection more than once? Or why do you want to use the same model for several tabs if you don't want them to share the data...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work the way I had it, so I placed the save button inside the view that has DataContext set to where employee's info are loaded and got it to work from there, since it directly accesses the properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I totally understand your question but if you need a Window with a tabcontrol, in which each tab refers to an employee, then you will have to bind the ItemsSource of the tabcontrol to a list of the ViewModel.

It is not possible to bind all tabpages to the same instance because then the tabpages will all do the same, and show the same information.

Comment: This sounds like what I'm trying to achieve. How can I go about binding the ItemsSource to a list of the ViewModel? Or will I need to post a new question in regards to this?

Comment: Actually I just did some checks and that's what I currently have at the moment but there is one problem. Every time I add a tab, the ViewModel gets instantiated again so when I go to save the info that is being displayed to my database, I get a NullPointerException. The save button is in another view and the DataContext of that view handles the TabControl Items (WorkspaceViewModel)

Answer (score 0):

ViewModels should have a 1:1 relationship with the model. In your TabControl's DataContext, let's say you have properties like:

```
public ObservableCollection<EmployeeViewModel> Employees {get;set;}
public EmployeeViewModel CurrentEmployee
{ 
    get { return _currentEmployee;}
    set
    { 
        _currentEmployee = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentEmployee");
    }
}
```

where Employees is bound to ItemsSource of the TabControl, and CurrentEmployee to CurrentItem. To create a new tab:

```
var employee = new Employee();
var vm = new EmployeeViewModel(employee);
Employees.Add(vm);
CurrentEmployee = vm;
```

If you want a save button outside of the TabControl, just set its DataContext to CurrentEmployee.

I hope this helps!

**Edit:**

Two things I think are causing problems:

1. Payroll.xaml should be bound to MainViewModel since that's where the Workspaces collection is.
2. Do not instantiate ViewModels in your view's code behind.  Use a DataTemplate instead (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446747/preferred-method-for-binding-in-mvvm-data-template-in-resources-file-or-just-da)).

Take a look at [Josh Smith's MVVM demo app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)  ([source code](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/1/A/D1A38A8A-B635-4A74-9B7B-1177F4297867/MvvmDemoApp.zip))

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try and accept as answer if it works :)

Comment: I added some code to show what I have so far. I tried your solution however bindings seem to disappear.